# Hilbert 10th problem for genus 2 equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory, decidability

Hilbert 10th problem, while undecidable in general, remains open for 2-variable equations: we do not know if there is an algorithm that, for polynomial $P(x,y)$ with integer coefficients, decides where there exist integers $x,y$ such that $P(x,y)=0$.

The difficulty of the problem seems to depend on genus. There are known algorithms for determining the existence of integer points on the curves of genus $g=0$ and $g=1$, so it is natural to look at next genus $g=2$. Standard examples of equations defining genus $2$ curves are
$$
y^2=P(x)
$$
where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $5$ or $6$ with integer coefficients and no repeated roots, but Baker discovered in 1969 an explicit upper bound for possible integer solutions of such equations, which of course implies the existence of an algorithm for listing all solutions.

There are other examples of equations defining genus $2$ curves. For example, Masser and Zanier found simple one-parameter family of genus $2$ equations
$$
x^4-y^3-axy=0
$$
for which it seems difficult to find all integer solutions. The Hilbert 10th problem, however, is trivial for this family, because $x=y=0$ is always a solution.

I did some experiments with 2-variable quartic equations with small coefficients and discovered (a) thousands of equations for which the problem of existence of integer solutions seems difficult, but they all happen to be of genus $3$, and (b) thousands of equations of genus $2$, but they all happened to have small integer solutions.

So, my questions are: do there exist an algorithm to solve the Hilbert 10th problem for all genus $2$ equations? If not, are you aware of any examples for which the problem seems difficult? Are there such examples of degree 4?

Comment: It seems that it is possible to bound the size of integral points on a hyperelliptic curve given by the standard Weierstrass model (given by Bugeaud, Mignotte, Siksel, Stoll, and Tengely https://msp.org/ant/2008/2-8/ant-v2-n8-p01-p.pdf), and since all hyperelliptic curves have a model of that shape, this is probably a reasonable answer (i.e., one can simply search points up to the height to determine if any of them is a solution). Of course, the bounds given for the heights are often far too large to be of practical use.

Comment: Check out page $2$ of Levin’s https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.6070.pdf !

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Unfortunately the transformation to that model introduces denominators which aren’t constant… But maybe I’ve misunderstood your comment (sorry if so!)! Anyway the introduction to Levin’s paper explains it well I think.

Comment: @alpoge, thank you for the reference but can you please explain how it answers the question? The introduction to Levin’s paper confirms that in general "Find an effective version of Siegel’s theorem for curves C of genus two" in an open problem. Then there is a discussion that the problem has been solved in a number of special cases. But I do not see whether the special case I am asking for ($O_{k,S}={\mathbb Z}$, and just determine the existence of an integer point, yes or no) is one of the cases that has been solved.

Comment: @BogdanGrechuk I can’t say I know the literature that well (and your point that the usual models that people use to show the difficulty of applying Baker to all models of hyperelliptic curves obviously have points is a good one!) but it seems to me the problem over $\mathbb{Z}$ is just as hard as the one over all $\mathfrak{o}_{K,S}$… I mainly noted the paper because Levin gives the models $y^3 + g_1(x) y^2 + g_2(x) y = x^4 + g_3(x)$ with each $g_i$ of degree at most $i$ —- I don’t see immediately how to decide the existence of an integral point for those, but let me know if you do!

Comment: @alpoge, as noted in the question, I performed a computer search of many thousands of equations and so far did not found a single example of genus 2 equations of this form for which the existence problem is non-trivial. Usually a curve of this form either has genus 3 or a small integer point. I started to suspect that there is a reason for this phenomenon and something like this is true in general, hence the question.

Comment: @BogdanGrechuk Unfortunately I have zero expertise concerning practical questions, but thousands doesn’t seem like that many unfortunately :(. There are quite a few parameters in the model I reproduced from Levin, and even ignoring the “law of small numbers” there is of course the issue that very-low-height curves which do have a point will have seemingly low-height points. But I certainly agree that there should be an algorithm! After all if you assume effective abc over number fields you get an effective form of Mordell (Elkies), thus Siegel —- I think the height bound isn’t even that bad.

Comment: @BogdanGrechuk All that to say: I don’t know! As in: I don’t know if there is a known explanation for the phenomenon you’re seeing in your computations, and I’d love to find out if there is! I haven’t thought much about heuristics, for example.

Comment: @OP Since you are interested in integral points, the correct invariant to be looking at here is the Euler characteristic of the smooth affine curve $U$, rather than the genus of the corresponding smooth projective curve $C$ (I believe you are implicitly doing the latter). These are related by $\chi(U) = 2g(C) - 2 - \mathrm{deg}(C \setminus U)$. Fixing the genus of $C$ is not really the right way to approach these kind of problems (e.g. if $g(C) = 0$ then one still gets difficult problems in trying to calculate $U(\mathbb{Z})$.)

Comment: Rather, one should consider here the case where $\chi(U) = 2$ (or even better $\chi(U) = 1)$.

Comment: @Daniel Loughran You may call "difficult problem" to resolve the $g=0$ case, but this difficult problem is completely solved by now, see papers of Dimitrios Poulakis https://eudml.org/doc/210230 and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717101905152 . The genus 1 case is even more difficult problem, but it was solved by Alan Baker and John Coates,  Integer points on curves of genus 1. In Mathematical Proceedings of the
Cambridge Philosophical Society, volume 67, pages 595–602. Cambridge University Press, 1970. So genus is also a natural parameter for this problem.

Comment: @BogdanGrechuk I said "difficult" not "unresolved"; I stand by this comment. In any case I just wanted to point out that in some respects the Euler characteristic is a more natural invariant than the genus here.

Comment: Yes, I agree that genus 0 and 1 cases, although resolved, deserve to be called "difficult". Thank you for your comment. I will think whether the problem becomes easier for small Euler characteristic.